# Adding tooltips for preconfigured date ranges in stock chart (Highstock)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add some tooltips for the preconfigured date range buttons (like 1 day, 1 month etc.) in stock chart in highstock. I am not able to find a way to do it.

[refer this link](http://highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui.)

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi @T Ravi Theja, Could you explain more precisely what you want to achieve?

Comment: Let's consider the preconfigured date ranges in stock chart like : https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui. I want to show 1 day on hovering 1d button, 1 month on hovering 1m button and so on .

Comment: @T Ravi Theja, So you want to have different tooltips (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip) for a specific preconfigured date ranges?

Comment: @ppotaczek, Yeah But I dont want it to affect my current tooltip for the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts doesn't have built-in tooltip for the `rangeSelector`, but still you can create your own tooltip for that. It is very simple to add events to the buttons:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var chart = this,
                    buttons = chart.rangeSelector.buttons;

                for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
                    (function(i) {
                        var item = buttons[i],
                            group = $('.highcharts-range-selector-tooltip'),
                            rectElem = $('.range-selector-tooltip'),
                            textElem = $('.range-selector-tooltip-text'),
                            box;

                        item.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                            // Define legend-tooltip text
                            var str = item.text.textStr;
                            textElem.text(str)

                            // Adjust rect size to text
                            box = textElem[0].getBBox()
                            rectElem.attr({
                                x: box.x - 8,
                                y: box.y - 5,
                                width: box.width + 15,
                                height: box.height + 10
                            })

                            // Show tooltip
                            group.attr({
                                transform: `translate(${e.clientX + 7}, ${e.clientY + 7})`
                            })

                        }).on('mouseout', function(e) {

                            // Hide tooltip
                            group.attr({
                                transform: 'translate(-9999,-9999)'
                            })
                        });
                    })(i);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    ...

}, function(chart) {
    var group = chart.renderer.g('range-selector-tooltip')
        .attr({
            transform: 'translate(-9999, -9999)',
            zIndex: 99
        }).add(),
        text = chart.renderer.text()
        .attr({
            class: 'range-selector-tooltip-text',
            zIndex: 7
        }).add(group),
        box = text.getBBox();

    chart.renderer.rect().attr({
            'class': 'range-selector-tooltip',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            'stroke': 'grey',
            'fill': 'white',
            'zIndex': 6
        })
        .add(group)
});
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lg9cfrub/

**API Reference**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.load